# Kdenlive importing at wrong framerate

Tags: 22.04, video, kdenlive

I am using kdenlive 23.04.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.

I seem to have changed a setting I can't find.  I have several webm files that were recorded with the gnome screen recorder.  When I play them in VLC, they are all just fine.

I can bring them into kdenlive just fine.  But one particular webm, when I bring it in it asks to change the profile to the "clip profile" of 1fps and then imports the video at 1fps.  I can't seem to change it back.

It still plays fine in VLC.  And any of the other files will import into kdenlive at appropriate framerates.

When I first started this project I had a low battery in my mouse and it caused a mis-click somewhere.  I cancelled whatever came up, but apparently it made some difference for how this one particular file gets imported.  Something is attached to this particular file.  A "clip profile".

I really don't want to have to re-record this.  How can I make kdenlive import it as is instead of converting it to 1fps every time?